# django-rest-framework: How do I create a Feedback / Contact form without a model?

Tags: forms, email, django-rest-framework

first-time poster. I’m trying to create a simple contact option using Django Rest Framework. The contact page would allow users and non-users to send the site admin an email via a form. Been at this for weeks… I’ve added my questions and code below.

1)  Is it the viewset that needs some additional work to connect to the form data?

2)  Does the DRF API viewer allow for testing this out? Should it be showing the email fields?

```
# serializers.py

class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer): 

    email = serializers.EmailField()
    message = serializers.CharField()
    name = serializers.CharField()

# views.py

class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request): #, format=None
        comment = CommentSerializer(data=request.data)
        if comment.is_valid():
            form_email = comment.data['email']
            form_message = comment.data['message'] + "email: " + form_email
            form_name = comment.data['name']

            send_mail("New contact form submission",
                form_message,
                form_email,
                ['myemailaddress@gmail.com'],
                fail_silently=False
            )
            return Response(comment.data)

        # Not sure how the html connects here:
        # return render('comment.html', {
            # 'form': form_class,
        # })       
        return Response(
            {
                "success": False,
                'error-code':'invalid-data'
            }, 
            )

# urls.py

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'profiles', views.ProfileViewSet)
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'comment', views.CommentViewSet, 'Comment') 

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the form rendered by DRF or is that some static page that sends ajax requests to drf ? I also don't get "Is it the viewset that needs some additional work to connect to the form data". What do you mean by connect here ?

Comment: At the moment, I'm trying to get the form rendered by DRF; however, I'm not sure if that's a best practice. As for my question about the viewset, I'm saying that I think that's where my problem is - I'm still a bit fuzzy about how everything connects up and terminology.

Comment: In case you missed it, form rendering is explained here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/

Comment: Thank-you, yes, I went over that page several times while trying to sort this out.